# ObjC++ calling static library written in C

Tags: c++, ios, c, opencv, ffmpeg

I have an iOS project utilizing ffmpeg (which is a pure C library) and OpenCV.

Since I use the C++ interface of OpenCV, I write objective-c++ which is a `.mm` file. But the file is not OK with ffmpeg, and Xcode complains about `undefined symbol` on linking stage.

I also use ffmpeg in another `.m` file and it is OK. So I am sure the problem is with `.mm` and static library written in C.

Comment: I think the problem you're encountering is similar to when mixing C and C++ code. What you need to do is to fix your C headers by wrapping it with `extern "C" { ... }`. Go have a look at this [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-personal.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using .mm you get c++ name mangling (as opposed to c name mangling).

Fix by adding an "extern c" wrapper to your c-function declaration (not needed for the definition)

```
extern "C" {

int somecallback(int param);

}
```

EDIT:
Usually c-header files has this wrapping arranged already, look for something similar to

```
#if defined  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

in the .h file, if not found then put the #include inside ypur own wrapper.

Comment: fixed by adding this around the #include directive